# Read content of text file and use it to change text of a TextBlock

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a Page (MainPage.xml) which has a TextBlock with "User" written on it.
I also have a file called Username.txt stored in the Isolated Storage.
How would I make the TextBlock change 'User' to the name supplied in the Username.txt (Preferably at run time/without having to press a button)

In my project I have 2 Pages, a settings view and the main view. The user gives inputs his name in the settings page, which then stores it in a .txt file for the main page to use.
The finished product is supposed to list a user's name, and some other info (eg. phone number, email and more).

Please keep in mind that I just recently started learning, so please bear with me if I don't fully understand something straight away :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I really don't think you have to read and write to the txt file. You can do is keep the data into some class through the app session. and save the data when you leave the app. And When you open the app again load the data from isolated storage into that class and use again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For storing settings in isolated storage I wouldn't use a file. Microsoft has already made something nice for us developers: the class `IsolatedStorageSettings`. It is basically a dictionary that writes to isolated storage. Storing a username is almost as simple as:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("username", "johndoe");
```

And then to retrieve the username:

```
var username = (string)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["username"];
```

There is are really nice example of storing settings on Windows Phone [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings(v=vs.95).aspx). The example uses just one page but you'll definitely get some insights that will free you from your headaches.

Comment: Oh thanks! I agree, using files was not the best solution, the IsolatedStorageSettings class is much better suited for this. Most things seem to work now, however I get a error "The given key was not present in the dictionary" when trying to retrieve the username from my MainPage. Did it not import correctly or am I missing something?

Comment: @MichaelG did you can .Save()?

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to that. Thanks a bunch! It's working perfectly now! :D